# iframe cannot open pdf file in firefox "no preview avilable"

Tags: html, pdf, firefox

i'm trying to open a pdf file in `Iframe`

```html
<div>
 <iframe src="https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf" frameborder="0" style="border: solid red 1px;"></iframe> 
</div>
```

I'll see "No preview avilable" message instead of pdf, but if add the same `iframe` somewhere below, it will work just fine.
It happens only in Firefox browser.
Also i cannot open pdf with `<object>` or `<ember>` tags in firefox

Comment: This sort of sounds like a bug report?  If it is a bug report, it would be better placed on Firefox's bugtracker.

Answer (score 0):

adobe.com forbids embedding, so the snippet I've added to your question displays this in the web console:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: “SAMEORIGIN” from “https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf”, site does not permit cross-origin framing from

When I download the PDF and try this locally, everything works for me.

"No preview available" sounds like you have 3rd party software interfering.